How to insert an internal link to an r workbook
I am creating accessible tables in r using a11ytable. I have a about 20 sheets in the workbook. Now I need to insert internal links to a 'Notes' page on each worksheet that contains data in table format. Has anyone managed this please?
I found a site using this
https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/openxlsx2/html/create_hyperlink.html
but when I try and add the code I get an error
I have also downloaded rapid.spreadsheets
My previously created workbook is called my_wb
x <- '=HYPERLINK(\"#Notes!B4\", "Text to Display - Link to Notes")'
my_wb$add_formula(sheet = "Table 1", x = x, dims = "D4")

Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
‘add_formula’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Workbook”


From the docs the a11ytables package builds on openxlsx whereas you are trying to add a hyperlink using openxlsx2. To add hyperlink to an openxlsx Workbook class have a look at https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/reference/makeHyperlinkString.html. For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Many thanks for your help! This sorted the issue :)
